# Is it possible to do a multi tenancy with Graphql and Sequelize?

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I have a rather tricky question about GraphQl and multi-tenancy.

Let's assume there are 3 tables, **OWNER**, **HOUSE** and **TENANTS**. I will describe them in Sequelize and GraphQl pseudo code:

Owner table (has multiple houses and multiple tenants)

```
const OWNER = sequelize.define('owner', {
  ownerId: type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  name: type: Sequelize.STRING
}

OWNER.associate = models => {
  models.owner.hasMany(models.house, {foreignKey: {name: 'ownerId', field: 'ownerId'}})
  models.owner.hasMany(models.tenant, {foreignKey: {name: 'ownerId', field: 'ownerId'}})
}
```

House table (belongs to owner and has multiple tenants)

```
const HOUSE = sequelize.define('house', {
  houseId: type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  ownerId: type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  name: type: Sequelize.STRING
}

HOUSE.associate = models => {
  models.house.belongsTo(models.owner, {foreignKey: {name: 'ownerId', field: 'ownerId'}})
  models.house.hasMany(models.tenant, {foreignKey: {name: 'houseId', field: 'houseId'}})
}
```

Tenant table (belongs to owner and house)

```
const TENANT = sequelize.define('tenant', {
  tenantId: type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  ownerId: type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  houseId: type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  name: type: Sequelize.STRING
}

TENANT.associate = models => {
  models.tenant.belongsTo(models.owner, {foreignKey: {name: 'ownerId', field: 'ownerId'}})
  models.tenant.belongsTo(models.house, {foreignKey: {name: 'houseId', field: 'houseId'}})
}
```

The owner graphql object

```
const OwnerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Owner',
  fields: () => ({
    ownerId: { type: GraphQLInt },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    houses: {
      type: GraphQLList(HouseType),
      resolve(owner) {
        return owner.getHouse()
      }
    },
    houseById: {
      type: HouseType,
      args: <args is not defined>
      resolve(owner) {
        return <???>
      }
    },
  })
})
```

Here are a few simple GraphQL queries:

```
ownerById = {
  type: OwnerType,
  args: {
    ownerId: { type: GraphQLInt },
  },
  resolve(parents, args){
    return models.owner.findOne({ where: args })
  }
}

houses = {
  type: GraphQLList(HouseType),
  resolve(parents, args){
    return models.house.findAll()
  }
}

houseById = {
  type: HouseType,
  args: {
    houseId: { type: GraphQLInt },
  },
  resolve(parents, args){
    return models.house.findOne({ where: args })
  }
}

tenants = {
  type: GraphQLList(TenantType),
  resolve(parents, args){
    return models.tenant.findAll()
  }
}
```

These client queries work:

```
{
  ownerById(ownerId: 1) {
    ownerId
    name
    house {
      houseId
      name
    }
  }
}

{
  houseById(houseId: 2) {
    houseId
    name
    tenant {
      tenantId
      name
    }
  }
}
```

What I need to make multi-tenancy to work is something like that:

```
{
  ownerById(ownerId: 1) {
    ownerId
    name
    houseById(houseId: 2) {
      houseId
      name
      tenant {
        tenantId
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to archive this or is that out of scope what GraphQl can do?

If yes, how would the graphql object `houseById` query look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're requesting with the `houseById(ownerId: 2)`, at least within the context of the data models you've described. There's a one-to-many relationship between Owner and House. Once you've fetched an Owner node by id (`ownerById(ownerId: 1)`), any fields for that node would be related to that specific node. So I'm not sure what you're trying to do by allowing the consumer to specify a different `ownerId` for one of the fields. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Are you just asking how to construct a request with multiple queries in it? Or are you asking how to filter "nested" (i.e. non-root) fields by one or more arbitrary arguments? Or something altogether else?

Comment: Sorry @DanielRearden `ownerId` should say `houseId`. My bad ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it seems like your resolver for `houseById` would not be that different from the resolver for the `houses` field on the same type.

```
houseById: {
  type: HouseType,
  args: {
    houseId: { type: GraphQLInt },
  },
  async resolve(owner, { houseId }) {
    const houses = await owner.getHouses({ where: { id: houseId } })
    return houses[0]
  }
},
```

For a `HasMany` association, the getter for the target model resolves to an array of instances. So we need to grab that array first and then return just the first item in it, since our field represents a single object and not a list. If you don't want to use async/await, you can also do:

```
return owner.getHouses({ where: { id: houseId } })
  .then(houses => houses[0])
```

It would also be worth mentioning that this sort of pattern for a schema defies convention. Rather than having a `houses` field, a `houseById` field, a `houseBySomeOtherArg` field, etc., consider exposing a single `houses` field with one or more arguments like `id`, `name` or whatever filter criteria you want to provide. Your field can then just filter the houses based on whatever arguments are passed in, or return all results if no filter arguments were provided.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you are right. I just forgot the `args` parameter in the `resolve()` function. At the end my field prop looks a bit different. Instead of passing `owner` and use the `getHouses()` function, I imported the **Sequelize** `models` and used the `findOne()` function like that: `resolve(owner, args) { return models.house.findOne({ where: args }) }`